# How do I retrieve synonyms of a word from WordNet using SPARQL on Jena Fuseki server?

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, wordnet

I am new to SPARQL. I tried the following query after uploading wnfull.rdfs onto my Jena Fuseki server:

```
PREFIX  wn20schema: <http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/>
SELECT  ?aSynset
WHERE   { ?aSynset wn20schema:containsWordSense ?aWordSense .
      ?aWordSense wn20schema:word ?aWord .
      ?aWord wn20schema:lexicalForm  "bank"@en-US }
```

to retrieve Synsets that contain a Word with the lexical form "bank".
Howevr, it didn't retrieve any results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The file you loaded contains just the schema, not the instance data of WordNet. (Wouldn't be the first step to looking into the file and check which data will be loaded?)

By the way, I would prefer the RDF version that matches the latest one from here: http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will check it out :)